# How to solve "kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized" of ActivityMainBinding

Tags: kotlin

I know that already been questions about this error but i cant find something similar to this case.

I'm randomly getting this exception. Most of the time it works ok but time to time i get this exception.
How can i work it out?

```
  Caused by kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
   at com.zzzzz.yyyyyy.base.MainActivity.getBinding(MainActivity.kt:96)
   at com.zzzzz.yyyyyy.base.BaseFragment.onViewCreated(BaseFragment.kt:128)
   at com.zzzzz.yyyyyy.presentation.inicio.view.InicioFragment.onViewCreated(InicioFragment.kt:60)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
   at com.zzzzz.yyyyyy.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:215)
   at com.zzzzz.yyyyyy.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:209)
   at com.zzzzz.yyyyyy.base.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:114)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4009)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

**My MainActivity.kt looks like:**

```
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        appUpdateManager=AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)

        presenter = MainPresenter()
        AndroidThreeTen.init(this)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragmentContainer)
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
   at com.zzzzz.yyyyyy.base.MainActivity.getBinding(MainActivity.kt:96)
   at com.zzzzz.yyyyyy.base.BaseFragment.onViewCreated(BaseFragment.kt:128)
```

You're getting this because a `BaseFragment` is trying (in its `onViewCreated` method) to access `binding` on `MainActivity` before the activity's `onCreate` method has run and set it.

Activities and Fragments have different lifecycles, and aren't necessarily created in the order you expect. It's also possible for a `Fragment` to be retained when its parent `Activity` is destroyed, [but the Fragment is in a state where its View is destroyed](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created_and_view_destroyed), and it just needs to recreate its `View`s (in `onCreateView`) instead of going through the whole `onCreate` process.

So you can't guarantee that the parent `Activity` is in the `CREATED` stage (i.e. has run `onCreate`) when the `Fragment` is running `onViewCreated`. There's a deprecated lifecycle callback, [`onActivityCreated`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) that tells you when that happens - the documentation tells you how you're supposed to handle it now, setting a `LifecycleObserver` on the `Activity` through the `onAttach` Fragment method (an *attached* Activity isn't necessarily in the `CREATED` state yet) and watching for the `CREATED` state, then removing the observer and doing what you need to do.

---

But the more important question is - why does your `Fragment` need direct access to its parent `Activity`'s view hierarchy anyway? They should be completely separate things, a `Fragment` should be self-contained. If it needs to communicate with the `Activity`, you can do that through things like callback listeners or wiring them together with a `ViewModel`. Whatever you're doing, there's probably a better way to do it!